# error_code 17 при аутентификации пользователя на сайте ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Есть Standalone-приложение VK.

Пользователь проводит OAuth-авторизацию для получения `access_token` по [документации](http://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile).

> Процесс авторизации приложения состоит из трёх шагов:
>
> 1. Открытие окна браузера для аутентификации пользователя на сайте ВКонтакте.
> 2. Разрешение пользователем доступа к своим данным.
> 3. Передача в приложение ключа `access_token` для доступа к API.

На третьем шаге начинается самое интересное — некоторые пользователи получают токен и всё работает, а некоторые получают `error_code 17` ([Ошибка при заходе из подозрительного места](http://vk.com/dev/need_validation)).

Пользователь выполняет процедуру проверки, описанную в документации, и получает следующего формата URL:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#success=1&access_token={НОВЫЙ ТОКЕН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ}&user_id={ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ}
```

Теперь пользователь пытается выполнить запрос к API уже с новым токеном и опять получает `error_code 17`.

Пользователи выполняют процедуру проверки несколько раз, так в итоге и не получив токен.

Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой или есть какие-либо идеи?

Comment: Приложение авторизуется и выполняет запрос с одного устройства и одного ip?

Похожая ситуация была, когда имитировал standalone и токен пытался использовать с сервера. Хостинг в Москве. Для пользователей из Москвы всё было ок, для других регионов – облом, как у вас.

Comment: @Sergiks Да, ситуация аналогичная Вашей: хостинг в Румынии, сам нахожусь в Украине, все украинские пользователи - ок, русские пользователи - требует валидацию. Как Вы решили данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Костыль А: указывать старую версию API (<3) в параметрах запроса. В таком варианте удавалось обходить капчу и другие ограничения по безопасности. Но это до тех пор, пока не отключат поддержку этих старых версий;

Вариант Б: не нарушать правила ВК и решать задачи методами, доступными для приложений типа Site/iFrame;

Вариант В: **делегирование**. Через Standalone работать от имени своих нескольких аккаунтов, авторизованных прямо с сервера, а клиенты пусть дают этим аккаунтам разрешения – админить их группы, рекламный кабинет и пр.

Comment: @Sergiks Варианты А и Б отпадают. А вот вариант В не доконца понял. Объясните на примере, если пользователю нужно поставить лайк, к примеру. Как он может разрешить это действие моему аккаунту?

Comment: Лайк – не сможет. Только standalone от имени того, что ставит лайк.

Описанный вариант годится для автомодерации групп, например. Вы, как владелец группы, добавляете мой «специальный» аккаунт как Менеджера группы. А этот спец. аккаунт у меня дал токен standalone приложению, которое от его имени следит, чтобы не было спама в комментах, чистит, банит. Так, напр., работает МДК'шный [анбан](http://unban.mdk.is/).

Answer (score 0):

Пользовался этим мануалом: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1659&rub=37

Comment: @shilgen это не подходит, потому что у меня standalone приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. 
Решение - при всех запросах использовать один и тоже ip и User Agent. 
Если получение токена, запрос, вернувший 17ю ошибку и проверка верификации производились с разных ip или User Agent - будет возвращать тот же токен. Необходимо полное совпадение на всех этапах.

Answer (score 0):

Для авторизации на стороннем сервере можно использовать этот скрипт - https://github.com/Yashko/vk-validation-node

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.