# Код ошибки 17: Validation required (VK API)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

После получения `code` от VK, получаю `access_token`.

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&code=%s&redirect_uri=%s
```

После этого, я пытаюсь получить данные от пользователя

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=".$data-user_id."&access_token=token&fields=photo_50&v=5.68
```

Но в этот момент, VK возвращает ошибку #17:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
["error"]=>
object(stdClass)#18 (4) {
["error_code"]=>
int(17)
["error_msg"]=>
string(65) "Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser 95232901"

["redirect_uri"]=>
string(69) "https://m.vk.com/login?act=security_check&api_hash=4a959bd2a476aea3fc"
}
}
```

**Но,** если я беру публичные данные, которые не требуют ключа, то всё хорошо

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=".$data-user_id."&fields=photo_50&v=5.68
```

В общем ошибка вылетает тогда, когда пытаюсь взять данные пользователя с ключом доступа.

---

https://vk.com/dev/need_validation

> В сообщении об ошибке передается также следующий параметр:
>   redirect_uri — специально составленный адрес, который необходимо открыть в браузере для прохождения процедуры валидации.

Но проблема в том, что когда пользователя перекидывает по ссылке в `redirect_uri` — <strike>он жмет кнопку "подтверждаю валидацию", и после это VK перекидывает пользователя сюда</strike>

VK автоматически проверяет пользователя через JS-скрипт, и перекидывает по конечной ссылке:

> https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#success=1&access_token=fsdf312fds4213321f&user_id=12345

И здесь **нету `back_url` на мой сайт**, а мне нужно считать `access_token`, и `user_id`. Как это сделать, если VK уже перекинул пользователя на страницу проверки, а потом уже на другой адрес?

Comment: https://github.com/dimka665/vk/issues/40

Comment: Там есть информация о том, из-за чего возникает ошибка, но мне бы как-то эти данные взять из конечной ссылки, или другой путь найти, а там пишут что после подтверждения все у них ок, но у юзеров у меня, даже после прохождения процедуры авторизации, опять такая ошибка вылезает.. (

Comment: Я читал читал и так и не понял какую проблемы вы в итоге решаете и после какого этапа. у вас всё в кучу. то ли токен не получате, то ли получаете но с токеном не работает метод, внезапно откуда-то еще `js` появился. .... зачем-то ссылку даете `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#` которая выпадает только для standalone приложений... как она связана со всем описанным выше - не ясно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я токен получаю пользователя, и когда пытаюсь с этим токеном получить инфу - выдает вот этот error_code 17. И прилогается еще redirect_uri по которому юзер переходит, и когда он переходит - там и выполняется эта проверка пользователя, после которой юзера переекидывает на [https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#](https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#)

Comment: Где вы откопали способ авторизации? Укажите точно какой способ вы используете и как тип приложения вы выставили в настройках. Судя по всему вы пытаетесь что-то делать со Standalone, хотя у вас не оно ....... и с вашим запросом `https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=".$data->user_id."&access_token=token&fields=photo_50&v=5.68` всё в порядке и он рабочий ...................а еще можно код php как вы это всё делаете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Такая ошибка выскакивает у 10% пользователей, у все остальных - окей все

Comment: @АлексейШиманский невнимательно читал про "тип приложения", стоит стандалоне тип, я не проверил сразу. Ответьте, я закину репу

Comment: @user190134 это решило проблему?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, у владельца приложения стоит тип не веб-сайт. А тогда кричал что веб-сайт. Но все-равно, такая ошибка выскакивает, как же в таком случае быть?

Comment: глянь сюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/377360/191482 .........

Comment: @АлексейШиманский напиши в ответ пожалуйста, я тебе присужу репу.

Comment: @user190134 попробуйте изменить тип приложения (судя по всему у вас standalone, переключите его на тип "web-сайт")

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_uri` это адрес, на который вернет пользователя после прохода и подтверждения по этой ссылке. В случае успеха, его вернет на эту ссылку вместе с кодом, при помощи которого можно получить токен. (За токеном должен обратиться сервер)

Собственно, все это есть в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user) вк с примерами и передаваемыми параметрами

Comment: Я чуть не так написал, access_token - я успешно беру, а вот когда пытаюсь данные о пользователе вытащить - тогда вот такую ошибку выдаёт.

Пробовал я и туда пихать redirect_uri - но оно не перекидывает обратно

Answer (score 0):

Такой трабл наблюдал когда страна сервера (на котором крутится скрипт) != со страной юзера. На сколько есть необходимость у Вас юзать oauth2?

Если нет необходимости юзать oauth2, то можно получить токен по прямой ссылке, с передачей гет-параметров логина и пароля, через оф. приложение (если интересно -- напишите, я поправлю ответ с ссылкой)

Comment: Постартайтесь дать развёрнутый ответ без уточнений у автора вопроса.

Comment: Я уже и не помню как решил вопрос если честно, вроде бы был неправильный тип приложения выставлен, я использовал через сайт, а тип был стандалоне (вроде-бы).